# run SqlTableDependency for update query as windows service

Tags: c#, sql-update, windows-services

I developed one program that use SqlDependency as windows service. but it not work.
I have Table dbo.Product in SQL Serve. I want when any records of this table updated, i get notification.

```
namespace MyService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.\myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb; User ID=user;Password=pass;";
        static int itemref;
        static decimal? quantity;
```

`public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterNotification();
    }

    private void RegisterNotification()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary> tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary>(connectionString))
        {
            tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_Changed;
            tableDependency.Start();
        }

    }


    void TableDependency_Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<ItemStockSummary> e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
        {
            var changedEntity = e.Entity;
            itemref = changedEntity.ItemRef;
            quantity = changedEntity.Quantity;
            UpdateProduct(itemref, quantity);
        }
    }

    void OnDataChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= OnDataChange;
        UpdateProduct(itemref, quantity);
        RegisterNotification();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
    }


    public void UpdateProduct(int item, decimal? quantity)
    {
        \\Do something
    }
}`

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please help others in answering your question by providing details of any error messages you're getting. Also, your code formatting is a little off. Have a look at the formatting guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3):

By calling using statement you are actually immediately disposing your sqlTableDependency instance.

```
using (SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary> tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary>(connectionString))
{
    tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_Changed;
    tableDependency.Start();
}
```

It looks like that you are trying to create a new connection each time you would otherwise receive an update.
Try to keep the connection in the following manner:

```
SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary> tableDependency;

private void RegisterNotification()
{    
    tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<ItemStockSummary>(connectionString))
    tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_Changed;
    tableDependency.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    tableDependency.OnChanged -= TableDependency_Changed;
    using (tableDependency) {}
}
```

This can fail on connection lost etc. so try to convert it also to [SqlTableDependencyProvider](https://github.com/tomasfabian/Joker/wiki/How-to-convert-from-SqlTableDependency-to-SqlTableDependencyProvider) for automatic reconnections. It is a wrapper around SqlTableDependency. SqlTableDependency does not support automatic reconnections in case of errors.